# (Asp.Net MVC3) How to Define StringLength for ASCII and Unicode?

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii, string-length

I have following define in model

```
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 10)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "XXX")]
        public string XXX{ get; set; }
```

Now I want it treat ACSII and Unicode input differently, for ASCII, each char consider length 1, so need min-length 10 and max length 50. But for Unicode char, I want to consider it length 2, so 5 unicode chars is enough for the minimal requirement.

How do I do it?

I guess I might need two approach, first overwrite the length check in asp.net, then I need to overwite the length check in jquery. Isn't it?

Is anyone here have a working sample, thanks.

Comment: The character data in .NET is always UTF-16. When talking about the encoded length, we also need to ask... is `"abc"` an ASCII string? or a unicode string? it is both (and neither!). Are you sure you couldn't just write a custom rule somewhere that checks the UTF-8 encoded length? (then the issue of "is it this vs that" is moot, as UTF-8 would meet both single-byte and multi-byte scenarios; it is a different encoding, though). To put that another way: what characters are you calling "unicode" here? just those >= 128?

Comment: I think how to test if a string a ascii string or unicode string is easy by using System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory

Comment: the unicode category does not tell you anything to do with ASCII. The only test for ASCII is: is it < 128. However, arguably abc etc are **both** ASCII **and** unicode.

Comment: To explain - here's a breakdown of the ASCII characters by category: http://pastie.org/2899860

Comment: Thank but I think we are missing the point here. All I want is to treat abc... length as 1 char, for unicode like chinese charactor as 2 char, how? For the simple string length function, theres no difference between them

Comment: Your requirements are strange. For example you can't even represent all unicode codepoints in 2 bytes. And of course even more codepoints have a UTF-8 representation that's longer than 2 bytes. Where does this requirement come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you should be able to introduce a custom validation attribute:

```
class FooAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int minLength, maxLength;
    public FooAttribute(int minLength, int maxLength) : this(minLength, maxLength, "Invalid ASCII/unicode string-length") {}
    public FooAttribute(int minLength, int maxLength, string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
        this.minLength = minLength;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        if(value == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
        var s = value as string;
        if(s == null) return new ValidationResult("Not a string");

        bool hasNonAscii = s.Any(c => c >= 128);

        int effectiveLength = hasNonAscii ? (2*s.Length) : s.Length;

        if(effectiveLength < minLength || effectiveLength > maxLength) return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(ctx.DisplayName));
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. Do I also need to write the jquery.validation myself? Or here is some shortcut

Comment: @Eric probably... although you could just let that one be handled server-side?

Comment: maybe not. Because the Jquery will think the string is too short and will never submit the data :)